# Prevent page from refreshing on button submit in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, chat

Im working in Dreamweaver cs5, which means that the php is automaticly created. I know some php but i cant figure out a way to prevent the page from reloading when i click the submit button. I dont want it to refresh because i am making a chatting service, where the refreshing just gets annoying. 
**Php which sends information to mysql database:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "send")) {
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO chat (chat_info, person_id, chat) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['chatid'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['personid'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['chat'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_LVGSChat, $LVGSChat);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $LVGSChat) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**Html form:**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="send" id="send">
    <input name="chat" type="text" id="sendtext" placeholder="Skriv en melding..." />
    <input type="button" id="sendbutton" value="" name="submit"/> 
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php do { ?><?php
    if (strtolower($row_medlemmer['brukernavn']) == strtolower($_SESSION['MM_Username']) ) {
        echo $row_medlemmer['medlemmer_id'];}
    ?><?php } while ($row_medlemmer = mysql_fetch_assoc($medlemmer)); ?>" name="personid" />

    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="chatid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="send" />
</form>
```

I have tried changing the type from submit to button, but it just stopped the whole script.

Comment: Then just use ajax.

Comment: @nicael I have no experience with ajax...Any chance you could show how i could implement ajax into this script? :P

Comment: @ReinBentdal see my answer, i have included a few links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem, one that can be fixed by using jQuery. What you're looking to do is an AJAX form submit. If you're not familiar with jQuery, [here is a jquery getting started guide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp).

Once you have added the jQuery script to head/foot of your document, you can then do AJAX form submits. To not rehash information, [check out this tutorial from scotch.io on AJAX Form submits](https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery). That tutorial will break it all down for you.

The main thing you're looking for is to call `preventDefault()` in javascript when your button is clicked, so I would read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to prevent page to refresh.

1) put javascript:; in form action.
2) use javascript or jquery and use ajax to pass data. i am sharing jQuery sample code.

```
  $("formID").on("click",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    ----another code to send data with ajax---
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! But i didnt quite understand what you ment. Where should this code be in the document and how should it be used? I have almost no experience with javascript :P

Comment: you can create a file named with custom.js or with any name then include that file in footer. That's it. You can add js code for site in that file.